# Expo | Google AdMob SDK | How to adjust timing for close button

Tags: react-native, admob, expo

I am currently using [Expo](https://expo.dev/) for a React Native application. I also use the [Expo AdMob](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/admob/) package. Currently in my Google AdMob dashboard I have an Interstitial ad configured. The video ad that shows up always has a 5 second timer for the close button.

How can I set this timer to be longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question here - apparently you can not as this is delivered as functioning from the ad provider